# Android how to restrist user for selecting same option in Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

i have 5 spinners in a layout and all contains same options say item1,item2,item3 in spinner,item1,item2,item3 in spinner2 so on, but i want restrict user for selecting same option spinner example if user select item1  in spinner1 then he is not allowed to select item1 in spinner2. can any one help me by giving some sample code for it .   .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061842/how-to-change-the-content-of-spinners-dynamically/9062103

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... Create five list , one for each Spinner . Now once he select item from any spinner , delete that item from List of other Spinners .

Google for notifyDataSetChanged() .